# Java string split gives array index out of bounds error

Tags: java, debugging, split

I came across this unusual error today. Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong. Below is the code:

```
AreStringsPermuted checkStringPerObj = new AreStringsPermuted();
String[] inputStrings = {"siddu$isdud", "siddu$siddarth", "siddu$sidde"};
for(String inputString : inputStrings){
    String[] stringArray = inputString.split("$");
    if(checkStringPerObj.areStringsPermuted(stringArray[0],stringArray[1]))
            System.out.println("Strings : " + stringArray[0] + " ," + stringArray[1] + " are permuted");
    else
            System.out.println("Strings : " + stringArray[0] + " ," + stringArray[1] + " are not permuted");
        }
```

The above code errors out at when i try to split the string. For some reason split does not work when I try to divide each string using "$". Can any one explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Below is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at arraysAndStrings.TestClass.checkStringsPermuted(TestClass.java:24)
    at arraysAndStrings.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:43)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.split()` [takes a regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), so you need to quote strings that contain characters that have special meanings in regular expressions.

```
String regularExpression = Pattern.quote("$");
for (String inputString : inputStrings) {
  String[] stringArray = inputString.split(regularExpression);
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, forgot that split looks for pattern as opposed to characters.

Comment: @Siddarth You're welcome. If my answer solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Stack overflow does not allow me to accept right away. Will accept in some time, you were too quick ;)

Answer (score 0):

String.split( ) uses regex partern and $ has special meaning in regex(the end of line).
In your case, use "\$" instead of "$".

```
String []arrayString = inputString.split("\\$");
```

For more information,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html